# Vue <a @click="manageCookies()"> performs a redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used to have the following code that worked smoothly:

```
<b-button @click="manageCookies()" variant="link">{{$t('app.cookies')}}</b-button>
```

A freelancer modified this code when redesigning the site this way:

```
<a @click="manageCookies()">{{$t('app.cookies')}}</a>
```

The problem is that I do not see the cookie dialog but the page is reloaded instead. This is the only difference. I suppose that the on click handler shall execute the javascript method, not the reload the page. The workaround is to add dummy href:

```
<a href="#" @click="manageCookies()">{{$t('app.cookies')}}</a>
```

Is this a correct way to handle the on click method?

Comment: Something i dont understand, you said "this code that worked smoothly". It worked smoothly, then it got edited and doesnt work anymore. Why did the freelancer changed it at the first place what was the intention?

Comment: I guess it was because of css. Other links were classic router links and this particular one was the button.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

use prevent click event like this:

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="manageCookies()">{{$t('app.cookies')}}</a>
```

this will prevent reload of page